# If holes are half as large as processes, the fraction of memory wasted in holes is:

Tags: probability, computer-science

If holes are half as large as processes, the fraction of memory wasted in holes is:

1. $2/3$
2. $1/2$
3. $1/3$
4. $1/5$

---

My attempt:

Somewhere it explained as:

Imagine processes as squares. If holes are also squares of half the side dimension of the processes (i.e. linear dimension is the largeness yardstick), then process area $= 4$ and hole area $= 1$. 
Then ratio of hole to total $= 1/5$ and you have your answer $(4)\space 1/5$ with a bunch of caveats.

Sorry, I didn't get the given solution, why processes as squares?

> Can you explain it, please?

Comment: I don't think you want the side length to be half, rather the area. After all, there are no actual squares in memory

Comment: Yes, right @HagenvonEitzen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think of memory as linear, not planar, because of the way it is addressed. Then you have as many holes as processes, so the fraction of holes is $\frac {\frac 12}{\frac 12+1}=\frac 13$

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.